# My clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS keeps freezing/hanging and needing to be force shutdown

Tags: 16.04, freeze

I'm able to use the computer just fine for anywhere from less than an hour to more than ten. It was from a fresh install - not an upgrade - that made it show this behavior. It's not just a freeze -- it's a hang, which requires me to force shutdown the computer. None of the cool Linux tricks I know or have researched work, including REISUB

I have no idea where to start. I've used Ubuntu without problems on several other older computers but for some reason it's affecting this particular one.

Hardware specs are listed here:
[image: Hardware Specs]

Comment: We have no idea where to start either. What about adding the hardware specs?

Comment: @celticWarrior Sorry, I was working on that. Is the update enough info for you?

Comment: Enough to know it has "Bay Trail" and that's a nightmare in Linux. AFAIK some Grub parameters are recommended precisely to avoid the problem you reported. But I don't know what you need exactly. Hopefully someone experienced in this kind of CPUs can answer. Meanwhile I suggest you google "bay trail ubuntu" and focus on the more recent results (results from 2013-14 may not be relevant now for 16.04).